# Ms Frontpage installation

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I want have MS Frontpage as Html editor on Ubuntu. This software is a part of MsOffice 2003 but is not part of it. I installed it by Wine and it installed whithout any error. But as I am try to open it, it crashes rapidly. In other hand PlayOnLinux have not any option for installation of Frontpage.